# Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, pointers

I'm just learning Cocoa (coming from C#) and I'm getting a strange error for something that seems really simple. (`charsSinceLastUpdate >= 36`)

```
#import "CSMainController.h"

@implementation CSMainController
//global vars
int *charsSinceLastUpdate = 0;
NSString *myString = @"Hello world";
//

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
...
}

//other functions
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"charsSinceLastUpdate=%i",charsSinceLastUpdate);
    if (charsSinceLastUpdate>=36) { // <- THIS line returns the error: Comparison between pointer and integer
        charsSinceLastUpdate=0;
        [statusText setStringValue:@"Will save now!"];
    } else {
        charsSinceLastUpdate++;
        [statusText setStringValue:@"Not saving"];
    }

}

//my functions
- (void)showNetworkErrorAlert:(BOOL)showContinueWithoutSavingOption {
...
}
//

@end
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your code, `charsSinceLastUpdate` is a **pointer**, you need to define it **without** the `*`:

`int charsSinceLastUpdate = 0;`

Unless, of course, you **meant** to define it as a pointer, in which case you'd need to use the [**dereference operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) to retrieve the value that it's pointing to, like so:

```
if(*charsSinceLastUpdate >= 36) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the * was just a common naming convention